# dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure) after discord update

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

After Discord got a new update I tried installing it with `sudo apt-get install discord` and got this error message. And how can I fix this linux-firmware error?

```
roxi@pop-os:~$ sudo apt-get install discord
```

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.197+system76~1620141009~20.10~f54d87c) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So then I assumed there is a problem with `linux-firmware` and found this post:

[dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure) after ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.1 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278876/dpkg-error-processing-package-linux-firmware-configure-after-ubuntu-18-04-t)
and followed suggestions from there.

For `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I got:

```
roxi@pop-os:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.197+system76~1620141009~20.10~f54d87c) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.137ubuntu12.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
```

For `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
roxi@pop-os:~$  sudo apt-get install -f
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.137ubuntu12.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.197+system76~1620141009~20.10~f54d87c) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
roxi@pop-os:~$  sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
```

For `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware`:
I got a pop-up windows that says: The volume "boot" has only 4MB disk space remaining.

And then tried `sudo apt autoremove` and got:

```
roxi@pop-os:~$ sudo apt autoremove
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-firmware (1.197+system76~1620141009~20.10~f54d87c) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess ret
urned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For proposed soultion `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware` got:

```
roxi@pop-os:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-firmware:amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manualy searching for kernels by `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep linux` and by purging them `sudo dpkg --purge <name>`